# PowerShell script for replacing value in a .txt file if it exist along with another one

Tags: powershell

I have a task to replace value in a `file1.txt` if this file exist along with another `file2.txt` in the same folder/subfolder. I have files with the same names in other subfolders but they do not exist together. Please help.

```
if($folder -contains ('Name.txt','Name2.txt')){
foreach ($file in $folder)
}
```

Comment: what code do you have? what did not work as needed?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of what you have already tried.

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected behavior is? Is it if `C:\example1\file1.txt` AND `C:\example1\file2.txt` then update `C:\example1\file1.txt`, but `C:\example1\file1.txt` AND `C:\example2\file2.txt` then do not update `C:\example1\file1.txt`?

Comment: @BenH file1.txt exists in couple of more folders and some subfolders, but in only one certain folder file1.txt lives along with file2.txt. If they are together I need to update variable in file1.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code appears to be the use of the `-contains` operator. Here's the page with the documentation. This is the relevant example:

```
PS> "abc", "def", "ghi" -contains "abc", "def"
False
```

Instead you could use `-contains` twice with the boolean `-and` or the `Compare-Object` cmdlet.

Possible Solutions:

```
$RootFolder = 'C:\example\'
$EditFile = 'file1.txt'
$DependentFile = 'file2.txt'


# Recursively get all folders
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory $RootFolder
```

Using -and

```
# Check each folder for the two files
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    # Get names of each file in folder
    $FolderContents = Get-ChildItem $Folder.fullname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
    # Check that the folder has file1 AND file2
    if ($FolderContents -contains $EditFile -and $FolderContents -contains $DependentFile) {
    }
}
```

Using Compare-Object

```
# Check each folder for the two files
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    # Get names of each file in folder
    $FolderContents = Get-ChildItem $Folder.fullname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
    # Compare the filenames in folder to an array of with two filenames, validate no extra elements found in second array
    if ((Compare-Object $FolderContents @($EditFile,$DependentFile)).SideIndicator -notcontains '=>') {
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me error at "$FolderContents = Get-ChildItem  $Folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name" and the error is: "Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'U:\Fold2' because it does not exist." I dont know why it is searching them in U: drive

Comment: @ИванЦанев Answer updated. The `Get-ChildItem` output needed to use the fullname property otherwise it uses your current working directory.